# XfBurner doesn't recognize USB stick

Tags: linux, usb, arch-linux, iso-image, burning

I want to make my USB stick bootable so I can install Ununtu but the USB stick doesn't appear in the drop down box in the "burn image" window of XfBurner. The stick is visible in Thunar file manager. This is the case for both my sticks. How do I solve this? I'm using Manjaro.

Comment: What application are you trying to use to burn the ISO?

Comment: XfBurner, as stated in the title

Comment: I have not used xfburner, but I don't think what you want is possible. I mean, I guess in theory you could write an ISO9660 FS to a flash drive, but I'm not sure why you'd want to (if you want a bootable OS, copy the files over and install Syslinux).

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear, I want to make a bootable USB stick so I can install Ubuntu. That's definetely possible

Answer (score 1):

In order to make an Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu, use the UNetbootin tool for creating bootable live USB drives (Windows/Mac/Linux/Ubuntu repositories). UNetbootin can be found in the Arch Linux Community repository. The flash drive you use should be 2GB or larger, plus whatever additional space on the USB drive you want to use for persistent file storage, and formatted to FAT32. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later it should be 4GB or larger.

UNetbootin will automatically format the USB flash drive to FAT32 if it is not already formatted to FAT32. In either case the formatting procedure will delete all of the files that are already on the flash drive.

It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Ubuntu live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable. In Arch Linux you can find the device name of the flash drive using the Palimpsest Disk Utility. In the picture below the name of the flash drive is `/dev/sdc1` where `/dev/sdc` is the device name of the flash drive and the 1 after sdc means UNetbootin will install the Ubuntu live USB on the first partition on that device.

[image]

In order to enable your computer to boot from the USB flash drive, you must enter your BIOS/UEFI setup utility by pressing one of these keys, usually: <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> as soon as the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting. In the BIOS/UEFI menu, you need to change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, save your new settings and exit from the BIOS setup utility.